# Search for StackExchange citations with Google Scholar

Tags: citations, google-scholar

Is it possible to use Google Scholar to search for publications that cite StackExchange users, questions, or answers?

<sup>cf. my Meta StackExchange question "[Publications that cite Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281161/257345)" or "[Academic papers using Stack Exchange data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134495/257345)"</sup>

Comment: Not to my knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297940/257345) to "[Publications that cite Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281161/257345)":

> [Legally](https://stackexchange.com/legal), anyone citing a Stack Exchange post must credit the author's user profile (among other things), which looks something like this:
>
> ```
> https://site.stackexchange.com/users/#####/username
> ```

A [Google Scholar search for "stackexchange.com/users/"](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22stackexchange.com%2Fusers%2F%22) yields many results.

Comment: Surely https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=stackexchange.com is the URL that is necessary in this case?

Comment: @user2768 Yes, that'll include more results. I'm only looking for articles that cite specific StackExchange users, not all articles that mention StakcExchange

Comment: @Geremia That's what the Stack Exchange TOS say, but in my view that provision is itself [illegal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209250/se-should-stop-using-the-cc-logo). Stack Exchange is not the copyright holder for that post; it is a licensee under a CC license, and does not have the right to add additional restrictions.

Comment: @Geremia You might like to clarify your question, because it makes no mention of such restrictions.

Comment: There is clearly no *legal* requirement for anyone citing Stack Exchange to formulate their citation in such a way that gives credit to the author's user profile.